# MySQL Incorrect date value: Sending 2015 but instead 2002

Tags: mysql

I am inserting this in my columns in

```
 PatientID       | int(3)
 DoctorID        | int(3)
 DrugID          | int(3)
 TreatmentResult | varchar(20)
 TreatmentDate   | date
 TreatmentTime   | time


INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES(1, 23, 1, 'etuigjih', 2015-03-10, '19:25:22');
```

But then it results to an error:

```
Incorrect date value: '2002' for column 'TreatmentDate' at row 1
```

Why does it send 2002 when my date is 2015?

Comment: You need single quote `INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES(1, 23, 1, 'etuigjih', '2015-03-10', '19:25:22');` for date values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the date value so it will be treated as a string, like this:

```
INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES(1, 23, 1, 'etuigjih', '2015-03-10', '19:25:22');
```

Otherwise MySQL will first treat that expression as 2015 minus 3 minus 10, which gives 2002, and then try to implicitly cast that as a date, which gives the error you saw.

To see where "2002" comes from:

```
mysql> select 2015-03-10;
+------------+
| 2015-03-10 |
+------------+
|       2002 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check your MySQL date:

```
select now() from dual;
```

I would suggest to use quotes for your insert command's date type:

```
INSERT INTO TREATMENT VALUES(1, 23, 1, 'etuigjih', '2015-03-10', '19:25:22');
```

Without the quotes it will not do, what you expect. But I cannot reproduce your error. Are you sure, that this was run as a standalone insert and was not part of a script? Which version of MySQL are you using and which client?

Comment: I am running mysql 5.6. I was applying this statement into my visual studio program where I could insert the date.

Comment: Ok, this sounds more like an additional problem on your program's side caused by the missing quotes, e.g. while parsing a string. On MySQL level I do not see any relation between your provided insert command and the '2002' string in the error message.